# WSO2 ESB Fronting a Rest Service with OAuth token validation - 202 Response

Tags: api, rest, oauth, wso2, esb

I am experimenting with WSO2 ESB to secure by REST APIs, by following this approach: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Securing+REST+APIs

My API configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="Test"
     context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
               <property name="STATUS" value="***** REQUEST HITS IN SEQUENCE *****"/>
             </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/document"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>

   </resource>
    <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.handler.SimpleOauthHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</api>
```

When I remove the handler section, I can see my service being invoked. But when I include the ouath handler, I can see my WSO2 Identity Server receiving the token validation call but the response from ESB is always HTTP 202.

curl -v -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer UQFffmYViFDxTHfCLOwDpjcX3qXZYQuiJ8EgJ_m-F1V7JTgqb6lbyA8QMT3" http://localhost:8285/document

```
> GET /document HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
> Host: 192.168.2.162:8285
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer UQFffmYViFDxTHfCLOwDpjcX3qXZYQuiJ8EgJ_m-F1V7JTgqb6lbyA8QMT3
>
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 20:44:57 GMT
* Server WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP is not blacklisted
< Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Any pointers on what am I missing or how I can debug would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact issue with my access token. Using the right token worked right. Also OAuth mediator can be used instead of handler.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="Test"
     context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="STATUS" value="***** REQUEST HITS IN SEQUENCE *****"/>
            </log>
            <oauthService remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9445/services/" username="admin" password="admin"/>    
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/document"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```